# How can I get the unshift method and this promise based code to work in this tutorial?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, express, promise

I am working on this **Node.js REST API with RBAC, JWT, Repository and MVC pattern.** It seems the author is no longer active with the post. There are [part 1](https://medium.com/@michael.svr/node-js-rest-api-with-rbac-jwt-repository-and-mvc-pattern-part-1-f5717c0b7103), [part 2](https://medium.com/@michael.svr/node-js-rest-api-with-rbac-jwt-repository-and-mvc-pattern-part-2-a494a4b89d7) and [part 3](https://medium.com/@michael.svr/node-js-rest-api-with-rbac-jwt-repository-and-mvc-pattern-part-3-648c7b5a4700). Part 1 and 2 works fine. But when I get to part three, I am having issue with two of the  files.

**ISSUE 1: THE JAVASCRIPT UNSHIFT METHOD**

When I added the unshift method in line 26 to 29 of the appBase.js file in part 3, the code refuse to resolve on loading when I tested it on postman. But when I remove it, it works fine. In part 1 and 2, it was not included.  From the code, the method `_createRouteBoundAction` now applies authenticate and authorize middlewares to each application route. This means that user has to have correct JWT token to access these routes. According to the author, the unshift method was meant to Authenticate and Authorize user by token. Why is the unshift not working? Is it because of the two parameters passed into it i.e. `this.security.authenticate(), this.security.authorise(controllerClass.name, method)`

```
_createRouteBoundAction(controllerClass, httpMethod) {
    const result = [
      (req, res) => {
        this._buildControllerInstance(controllerClass, req, res)[httpMethod]();
      }];

      result.unshift( 
        this.security.authenticate(),
        this.security.authorise(controllerClass.name, httpMethod),
    );

    return result;
  }
```

**ISSUE 2: getURI FUNCTION FAIL TO RESOLVE**

When I make the suggested changes in part 3, the getURI function fail to resolve in the URIGenerator.js file inside the routing folder. That is, when I tested it in Postman, the test keep loading and fail to resolve.

```
const queryString = require('query-string');
const RoutesCollection = require('./routesCollection');

class URIGenerator {
  constructor(security, role) {
    this.security = security;
    this.role = role;
  }

  getURI(controllerAction, params, id) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const caArray = controllerAction.split('_');
      const routeData = RoutesCollection[caArray[0]][caArray[1]];
      this.security.hasAccess(this.role, routeData.controller, routeData.action, (err, can) => {
        if (can) {
          const uri = params ? this._bindParams(routeData.uri, params) : routeData.uri;
          resolve({ id: id || routeData.action, method: routeData.method, uri });
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  _bindParams(uri, params) {
    let match;
    let replacement;
    const replacedParams = [];

    while (match = /:([\w_]+)\??/ig.exec(uri)) {
      replacement = params[match[1]].toString() || '';
      if (replacement === '') {
        uri = uri.replace(`/${match[0]}`);
      } else {
        uri = uri.replace(match[0], replacement);
        replacedParams.push(match[1]);
      }
    }

    const paramsForQueryString = {};
    Object.keys(params).forEach((p) => {
      if (!replacedParams.includes(p)) {
        paramsForQueryString[p] = params[p];
      }
    });

    if (Object.keys(paramsForQueryString).length > 0) {
      uri = `${uri}?${queryString.stringify(paramsForQueryString)}`;
    }

    return uri;
  }
}

module.exports = URIGenerator;
```

Meanwhile, when I use the getURI function as it was in part 1 it works. So, I am thinking it's because the getURI function fail to resolve.

Comment: `unshift()` issue: try removing the hanging comma from the parameter list.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 if you mean the comma after the httpMethod, I did before but it's not working.

Comment: There's no apparant need for `.unshift()`. Can you not simply build `const result = [a, b, c]`?